# Je pourrais vous écrire par la suite la réponse

Tags: adverbes

Quelqu'un m'a posé une question. Je lui ai dit que je ne connaissais pas la réponse et que si je trouve des informations, je pourrais lui envoyer un message.

> Je pourrais vous écrire **par la suite** la réponse.
>
> **Par la suite**, je pourrais vous écrire la réponse.
>
> Je pourrais **par la suite** vous écrire la réponse.
>
> Je pourrais vous écrire la réponse **par la suite**.

D'après vous, quelle variante est préférable ? Je pense que la deuxième et la troisième phrases sont les plus belles.

Answer (score 1):

Selon moi, la phrase la plus adéquate serait :

> Je vous répondrai plus tard, lorsque j'aurai la réponse.